# Updating Corporate Wifi using Command Line

Tags: windows, command-line, updates, remote

So i'm trying to update our Corporate Wifi SSID and password.

Currently we do not have a RADIUS server so using GPO and push profile to users and authenticate it with RADIUS is not an option.

in windows 7 it's storing the profile under C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Wlansvc\Profiles\Interfaces\

My question is how to update / remove/ change the profile using command line remotely?

I want to push the profile with new SSID and password to users without release the information to them.

Is it possible??

Comment: Have a look at http://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/using-netsh-commands-for-wi-fi-management-in-windows-8.html for the NETSH commands and then look over http://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html and see the section that talks about `=set - Update configuration settings on a remote machine.netsh set machine [name=] [user=][[DomainName\]UserName] [pwd=][Password | *]` and incorporate that into what the first article shows, etc. to test and confirm if this will work for your need in your environment. I cannot confirm but super quick research shows this potentially.

Comment: See here too: http://www.windowscentral.com/how-manage-wireless-networks-using-command-prompt-windows-10

Comment: Good deal evilrod... Be sure to accept your answer as well...  see [Accepting An Answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more detail on this if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

able to use GPO to push .bat script as user logon to import the new profile using .xml file with netsh wlan command. and then delete the existing one.

```
netsh wlan add profile filename="Path of xml"
```

then view and delete the old one

```
netsh wlan show profile
netsh wlan delete profile name="profile name"
```

Thank you all